# Keycloak - receiving account service roles in JWT token, but expect custom roles

Tags: jwt, authorization, keycloak, access-token

I use Keycloak to authenticate users. I have created new realm(*Efairy-realm*), client(*efairy-backend*) and new roles(*user*, *moderator*, *admin*). It looks like that:

[Config 1 look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr2xo.png)
[Config 2 look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWAIm.png)

The problem starts in access_token:

```
{
  "exp": 1619466995,
  "iat": 1619466935,
  "jti": "fcd20273-fb45-408c-9e20-126653d69719",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/efairy-realm",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "b1d89dc2-c12d-4c80-beed-c9a6065ec604",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "efairy-backend",
  "session_state": "d4a2b283-2f54-4a17-9a27-99db26278ba7",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "",
    "http://localhost:8083"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "efairy-backend": {
      "roles": [
        "uma_protection",
        "user"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "profile roles email",
  "clientHost": "172.23.0.1",
  "email_verified": false,
  "clientId": "efairy-backend",
  "groups": [
    "offline_access",
    "uma_authorization"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "service-account-efairy-backend",
  "clientAddress": "172.23.0.1"
}
```

I've created new user called *moderator* with role *moderator* and when im loggin to this user I' receiving roles(*resource_access.efairy-backend.roles*) that I set in tab *Service Account Roles*, but i would like to get roles that i declare in new user called *moderator* in *Role Mappings* tab.

[User roles looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQKrB.png)

Login flow looks like this:

1. Im redirecting user from my frontend app to keyclock login page with those params: */auth/realms/efairy-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=efairy-backend&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8083/auth-redirect-url*
2. Then Im entering proper user and password, and *click Sign in*
3. After successful sing in Im redirecting to frontend app, and make request for token with params:
   */auth/realms/efairy-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token*
   *grant_type: client_credentials*
   *client_id: efairy-backend*
   *client_secret: <client_secret>*
   *code: <secret_code>*
4. Response:

   access_token: "eyJhbGciO...AjbA",
   expires_in: 60,
   not-before-policy: 1619128217,
   refresh_expires_in: 1799,
   refresh_token: "eyJ...XQ_R0",
   scope: "profile roles email",
   session_state: "fcf1391d-...b11795c03f80",
   token_type: "Bearer",

Anyone know how to fix it? :)

Answer (score 1):

> After successful sing in Im redirecting to frontend app, and make
> request for token with params:  
> /auth/realms/efairy-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token 
> grant_type: client_credentials 
>  client_id: efairy-backend 
> client_secret: <client_secret> 
>  code: <secret_code>

When you do this the token will be omitted on behalf to the user `"service-account-efairy-backend"`, which is a user created by Keycloak for the client "efairy-backend".

> I've created new user called moderator with role moderator and when im
> loggin to this user I' receiving
> roles(resource_access.efairy-backend.roles) that I set in tab Service
> Account Roles, but i would like to get roles that i declare in new
> user called moderator in Role Mappings tab.

You are getting the roles that you set in the *Account Roles* because those roles are assign to the client (*i.e.*, the user `"service-account-efairy-backend"`). And because the user `Moderator` is not part of that interaction the role `moderator` is not part of the token.

Moreover, client credentials is not an appropriate flow for front-end apps. From [source](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/client-credentials-flow) one can read:

> **Client Credentials Flow** 
> With machine-to-machine (M2M) applications,
> such as CLIs, daemons, or services running on your back-end, the
> system authenticates and authorizes the app rather than a user. For
> this scenario, typical authentication schemes like username + password
> or social logins don't make sense. Instead, M2M apps use the Client
> Credentials Flow (defined in OAuth 2.0 RFC 6749, section 4.4), in
> which they pass along their Client ID and Client Secret to
> authenticate themselves and get a token.

It seems to me that your third step can be removed. After the second step:

> Then Im entering proper user and password, and click Sign in

you should have a token omitted on behalf of the user `Moderator`.